# Two ways binding (from multiple text boxes to single text area in JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am bit of situation where i needed to update data from `text-box` (multiple) to Text area.

I have 5 textboxes in which i am entering names and one text area where i am updating automatically according to name change in text boxes.

textbox 1 = "i",textbox 2 = "am",textbox3 = "trying ",textbox4 = "to ",textbox5 = "concatenate"

Then, 
Text area should show. - i am trying to concatenate.

Now if i update anything in text area like i changed "trying" to "tried" and then after that i changed something in textbox1 like "I" to "we" then in text area it should not replace the "tried" word again.

I am trying to do this using jquery. Is there any solution for this, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I have updated my code below.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Change any input value and the textarea gets updated.

```js
$(function () {
 var arrInitial;

 $(".inputField").on('focus', function () {
  arrInitial = [];
  $(".inputField").each(function () { arrInitial.push($(this).val()); })
 });

 $(".inputField").on('blur', function () {
  //If text area is blank then update all input values
  if ($.trim($("#txtArea").val()) === "") {
   var inputValues = "";
   $(".inputField").each(function () { inputValues += " " + $(this).val(); })
   $("#txtArea").val($.trim(inputValues));
  }
  else {
   //Get existing values from text area and split by " "
   var arrData = $("#txtArea").val().split(" ");
                        var arr = arrData.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
                        var arrNew = [];

   $(".inputField").each(function (i) {
    if (arr[i] === arrInitial[i]) //Check against initial values in text fields
     arrNew.push($.trim($(this).val()));
    else
     arrNew.push(arr[i]);
   });

   $("#txtArea").val(arrNew.join(" "));
  }
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1" value="One" class="inputField">
<input type="text" id="input2" value="Two" class="inputField">
<input type="text" id="input3" value="Three" class="inputField">
<input type="text" id="input4" value="Four" class="inputField">
<br/><br/>
<textarea id="txtArea" rows=10 cols=10 value=""></textarea>
```

Comment: *"Now if i update anything in text area like i changed "trying" to "tried" and then after that i changed something in textbox1 like "I" to "we" then in text area it should not replace the "tried" word again."* - from the question.

Comment: Didn't noticed the requirement properly. Updated the code. Assuming the text updated in textarea is separated by " ".

Comment: It works at some extent. Problem is when we add space in text area, Some data got missed.

Comment: Updated my code to remove blank spaces. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inputText").keyup(function(){
    $('#result')[0].innerHTML=$('#one').val()+$('#one1').val()+$('#one2').val()+$('#one3').val()+$('#one4').val();
    //$("input").css("background-color", "pink");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="inputText" id="one"/>
<input type="text" class="inputText" id="one1"/>
<input type="text" class="inputText" id="one2"/>
<input type="text" class="inputText" id="one3"/>
<input type="text" class="inputText" id="one4"/>
<br /><br />
Result:
<textarea id="result"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.innerHTML`? Why not just `.html()` or `.val()`? *"Now if i update anything in text area like i changed "trying" to "tried" and then after that i changed something in textbox1 like "I" to "we" then in text area it should not replace the "tried" word again."* - from the question.